# Why the derivative of the logarithm of a theta function is not an elliptic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

Let's consider the theta functions periodicity conditions
$$\vartheta\left(z+1\right) =\vartheta\left(z\right),$$
$$\vartheta\left(z+\tau\right) =e^{-\pi i\tau-2\pi iz}\vartheta\left(z\right),$$
Those imply conditions on the derivatives of theta functions
$$\vartheta'\left(z+1\right) =\vartheta'\left(z\right),$$
$$\vartheta'\left(z+\tau\right) =e^{-\pi i\tau-2\pi iz}\vartheta'\left(z\right),$$
Therefore if I take the derivative of the logarithm I should have an elliptic function since
$$f(z)=\frac{d}{dz}log\left( \vartheta\left(z\right)\right) =\frac{\vartheta'\left(z\right)} {\vartheta\left(z\right)}$$
then we have
$$f(z+\tau)=f(z)=f(z+1).$$
Anyway this can't be since it has only one pole in the fundamental period, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 
$$\vartheta(z+\tau)
=e^{-\pi i\tau-2\pi iz}\vartheta(z)$$
you get
$$\vartheta'(z+\tau)
=e^{-\pi i\tau-2\pi iz}\vartheta'(z)
-2\pi i e^{-\pi i\tau-2\pi iz}\vartheta(z)$$
and so
$$\frac{\vartheta'(z+\tau)}{\vartheta(z+\tau)}
=\frac{\vartheta'(z)}{{\vartheta(z)}}
-2\pi i.$$
Therefore $\vartheta'/\vartheta$ is not an elliptic function
but $(\vartheta'/\vartheta)'$ is (essentially the Weierstrass $\wp$-function).

Comment: What does it change with $f\left(z\right)=\sum\lambda_{k}\frac{d}{dz}log\vartheta\left(z-p_{k}\right)+C$? I know in this case can be elliptic if $\sum\lambda_{k}=0$

Comment: @Dac0 In that case, the $-2\pi i$ becomes $-\sum2\pi i\lambda_k$....

Comment: Shark  You are definitely right :D :D :D